# Changing a declared var inside a function

Tags: javascript

I need help with my script. Basicly my problem is that i have a variable declared with null, then inside a function changed to some value and then returned. But when i return it it still returns as null, not the thing i set it to. Anyone here to help?

**Script:**

```
var grade=""
var gradeStyle=""
var finalColor=""
function getSettings(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get("grade",function(res){
        grade=res.grade
    })
    chrome.storage.sync.get("gradeStyle",function(res){
        gradeStyle=res.gradeStyle
    })
    chrome.storage.sync.get("finalColor",function(res){
        finalColor=res.finalColor
    })
    return [grade,gradeStyle,finalColor]
}
export {getSettings};
```

Comment: Is `sync.get` async?

Comment: Those `chrome.storage.sync.get`s are all async functions. Your `return` is returning the initial values [before those functions have resolved](https://reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/nr1zvn/how_to_return_value_from_chromestorage/). (I normally wouldn't link to Reddit but the dupe I found on here was way too verbose, and that solution summed it up pretty well.)

Comment: Ok, i get it. That would work, but what if i need to return multiple in one function? just like i showcased. I dont want to create a function for every one of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are null because you are assigning these variables inside a callback function before returning them. It means that, the return values will not be assigned to variables until the promises completely resolves. To solve that, you can use the `async-await` syntax.

```
async function getSettings(){
    const grade = await chrome.storage.sync.get("grade").promise();
    const gradeStyle = await chrome.storage.sync.get("gradeStyle").promise();
    const finalColor = await chrome.storage.sync.get("finalColor").promise();
    return [grade,gradeStyle,finalColor]
}
export {getSettings};
```

Note that, to use the `getSettings` function now, you have to call it inside another `async` function, and you should `await` for its returning results.

Comment: This is what worked for me! Thanks a lot! The last part that the calling function should also be async is very important in this case. Thanks a lot

Comment: I am happy that it helped you. If you can mark the answer as accepted and give me an upvote, I would be highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
var response;
function getSettings(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get(["grade","gradeStyle","finalColor"],function(res){
    response=res;
    });
    return res;
}
export {getSettings};
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for that. I suppose they are asyncronous as well. The solution you submited doesnt work tho. It throws this error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'grade')
    at getSettings". Any idea?

Comment: Wrap the entire thing in a promise and return the value using resolve().

Comment: Could you please tell me how? i have not worked in js that much and i have no clue what promises are

Comment: This seems to not work. If I add console.log(res) behind any of the res=..., it logs undefined. I suppose that is not what it should be doing, but i have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: According to this https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/, it uses chrome.storage.sync.get(['key']), so try to change your code from "grade" to ["grade"]

Comment: Ok, so that didnt work but it gave me an idea. Basicly the fakt that [] is a list, it can return a list. And it actually does. So if you do `chrome.storage.sync.get(["grade","gradeStyle","finalColor"],(res)=>{console.log(res)}]` it actually prints all of them in a list, which can then be returned in one go. Thank you so much for suggesting this, i would be stuck on this forever if you didnt!

Comment: Ok still not working like that. Is it possible to return res in this code? `function getSettings(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get(["grade", "gradeStyle", "finalColor"],(res)=>{
        return res
    })
}
` and actually return it into getSettings and not just into the arrow function? @StefanoLeone

Comment: If your code doesn't work, try my edited answer.